# Can't move mp3 files from my laptop to my microSD card

Tags: sd-card, transfer

I remember being able to do it with Ubuntu 16.04. Yet, I am no more able to move music files from my computer to the SD card. It just doesn't react. Can you help me troubleshooting ?

[image]

When I try to do it with the right click I got :

```
Error opening file '/media/antoine/V/Music/Imagine Dragons - Demons.mp3': Read-only file system
```

Comment: Check the sdcard and verify you don't have the write protector switch set.

Comment: @L.D.James Yes, that was the issue ! Such a dumb question then ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The read only mode is the write protection switch.  Most SDCard have this.  Sometimes handling it can cause it to accidentally be turned to the protection side.

Check it when there's a problem writing to the media.